# BJT: How can the potential of B be above that of C during saturation?

Tags: bjt, saturation

I'm learning how BJTs work. As I understand, the B-E junction acts as a diode. This should mean that the potential of B can never be much higher than E besides the usual forward drop of a usual diode (like some 1.1V), because it is a low-impedance input and otherwise an unbounded current would arise.

However, a BJT's saturation voltage in datasheets is usually given as atleast 1.5V, meaning it is somewhat higher than the (assumed) maximal forward voltage drop from B to E. I can understand saturation mode when considering "Ice<Ibe x hFE". But when someone explains saturation as potential of B being higher than potential of C, I find it confusing, because if that were ever the case, wouldn't conventional current then flow in absolute terms from B to C (ie C would see a negative current)? The way I see it, the potential of C can and would always be higher than B, while "Ice<Ibe x hFE" would still hold and can still be the case, ie saturation can still occur.

I've come across [this](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Etraylor/ece112/beamer_lectures/bjt_reg_of_op.pdf) which contains important hints. It claims Vce can be lower than Vbe, but its claim of Vce being 0.2 isn't backed with references to datasheets, which usually only show the max value, and it is usually higher, such as for [BD241C](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/308/BD241C_D-1803068.pdf). So I should assume Vce 1.2V is a max value, and the lowest can be zero? When does the worst case happen, how does one know?

Update:
The falstad simulator was very helpful. I was under the false assumption that there can be a case where a voltage source not limited in current, can allow a bjt to saturate. Everytime I hear "B higher than C", I assume this is possible at considerable voltages above E. The simulator made clear this never happens, and that something must limit the current for the voltage of C to drop enough that B can be above it, and that this is the saturated mode, and that typical values for voltage of C are then lower than what is given in datasheets, which I assumed was the minimum possible value (which also previously made me averse to considering them, because I thought they were horribly inefficient relative to mosfets).

Comment: A saturation voltage of 1.5 V is actually pretty high; common BJTs typically have saturation voltages of 0.1 to 0.2 V.

Comment: The reverse bias of the base / collector junction is not a necessity for transistor action to take place. A transistor works just fine with base and collector connected i.e. at the same potential. OK, in making that connection you have restricted the circuit use to that of a diode but, there will still be decent current gain.

Comment: @Andy aka: Can you rephrase that as "potential of X higher/lower than potential of Y" because anything else requires convention, and from what I read people keep mixing up what is the source point, what is the target point, and whether a forward/positive voltage means source is higher than target or vice versa. Btw, I didn't constrain anything. It seems you misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Hearth: For example, the datasheet of BD679A states Vce(max) as 2.5 vs 2.8V. I assume this is a typical bjt?

Comment: @moFEAR The BD679A is a Darlington pair; Darlington (and Sziklai) pairs necessarily have a "saturation" voltage higher than the base-emitter voltage, because it's not possible to saturate both transistors in such a configuration.

Comment: @moFEAR What Andy said is talking about the potential of the base being *equal* to the potential of the collector, not higher or lower.

Comment: @Hearth: How can both potentials be equal? What voltages are we talking about? Like 10V or 100V above E? Wouldn't that cause an effective short-circuit as it is a diode?

Comment: @moFEAR It doesn't matter what the potential is relative to the emitter. The point is that it works that way.

Comment: @Hearth: Ok, but the question is how/why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141271/discussion-between-mo-fear-and-hearth).

Comment: Also, you appear to be looking only at power BJTs, which have higher saturation voltage by dint of being measured at higher current densities, and Darlington pairs, which have higher saturation voltage because you can't drive both transistors of the pair into saturation. If you look at more common BJTs like the [2N3904](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/2N3903_D-1773675.pdf), you'll see saturation voltages in the 0.2 to 0.3 volt range. Power BJTs are rarely used these days; vertical MOSFETs are usually better for power applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BJT: How can the potential of B be above that of C during saturation?

ANSWER: Because during saturation, Vcb changes from reverse to forward-biased decreasing Vce or making B above C.  The saturation region depends on Ic so it varies from 0.05V to 1.5 at max current.  There are also extremely high hFE transistors (>1000) and some with extremely low Vce(sat) with high current in bulk low hFE devices.  Some are better for RF, some for general-purpose or switching with low Vce.

The PN2222A is a classic plastic version of the metal can 2N2222A with hFE> 150 +/-50% or more and Rce = 1 to 2 ohms and the 2N3906, 2N2904 are 2 to 4 Ohms as a high current switches.

This depends on doping ratios and hundreds of other patented features by Diodes Inc. (nee Zetex), on semi (nee Fairchild) etc.

[image]

However, all real diodes and transistor collectors have bulk resistance causing additional I*R=V rise. For this reason, due to the size of the chip, this bulk series R will be inverse to the power rating R= k/Pmax near the rated current for k<=1 with big tolerances. These also affect all the tolerances in LEDs and Vce(sat).

So when you see Vce(sat) = 1.5V know that when C=B or Vce=Vbe at some current it is still in saturation and will continue to increase hFE from 10% to 100% at max collector current up to Vce= 2V. This is the reason audio power amps have worse THD distortion when Vce is < 2V.  But at least it still is a current pump so they call saturation threshold at max current often near 1.0 to 1.5V depending on the Ic/Ib=10 ratio.

At low currents when C is above B, Ic= is controlled by the Vbe with usually some high hFE.

But when C is below B, the BC junction starts conducting and reduces the current gain rapidly so as a switch the hFE is commonly rated at Ic:Ib=10:1.

[Falstad simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzAsBOJyWoGwgIxkmgzHAExoDsArHggByZpn0hx4iEhkRkCmAtJpgFCYSrQmCos4EIRkKTwIEmyU4y8lSABCAQwDOnEADUA9gBsALloDmnfgHcQeMiLIZHrPGDhY7Dpy1m%20ImLeQu5%20mITibiAIGBCKeJDMicwQaZCqAMKmJpwAxmZGAE6GphbW-JaBDp7VeKJq-GY1XrIQ0W3ymFAUTnhokmRwaGhiqbiEwvUkCHyhYC5YEAAmnABmWgCu5j6dnR6tcgIl0RFR4SRxSzD8AA4OVK0BeI8si91pdy0swR3BH%20AvgcJO1asCAWAfH9zqxpID7MDRFFap1IQi-MDMbU0dVCM9XnivDiOosXq1FpCSkiQTTUdcbiU0FRxJNWCQURT6fwgA) is ideal 2nd order, in that it follows the square law but no bulk resistance and thus hFE is constant.

There are over **3 million** [MMBT2222A-7-F parts in](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30041.pdf) Digikey stock at any given time making it still the most popular. Five cents @ 1k pc.

[image]
[image]

**This plot supports everything I explained above in one picture.**

Next up to saturate your brain (lol) why do diodes perform well as an analog thermometer.
[image]

Comment: Thx, I'm currently absorbing this...

Comment: The Falstad simulator is amazing. But how can I create my own sliders, for arbitrary parameters, such as a resistor? Currently, I open the edit box and keep applying new values, which is tedious.
Update: Found it. Just right click on the component after placement, and choose "sliders"

Comment: You can also use the mouse wheel on any passive part. @moFEAR . and use ^Z, ^Y for undo, redo. I still haven't explored all the features.

Comment: I just thought of a way to simulate reduced hFE during saturation.  Add a Schottky diode across BC then hFE of 100 reduces to 10 at 3mA 0.3V https://tinyurl.com/2jasmb2a. Export link shortcuts only work in comments and long form in answers/ questions. I once designed a discrete PCM telemetry Wheel speed encoder with random data one afternoon using Infineon chip specs for GM.... Yah Falstad rules with rubber band lines and resizeable parts

Answer (score 0):

> BJT: How can the potential of B be above that of C during saturation?

We most commonly understand current as *drift* current. Drift current is caused by electric fields. Electrons (and also holes) tend to move in the presence of an electric field. However, there is another form of current, and it is vital to understand this form of current to understand transistors. This second form of current is *diffusion* current. All electrons (and holes) are moving randomly because of thermal energy. If there is a region of high charge density near a region of lower charge density, then charges will tend to randomly diffuse from one to the other. That is, the gradient in charge density is what "drives" diffusion current. Perhaps surprisingly, *diffusion* current can travel in a direction contrary to that which one would expect from an electric field which is present.

In an NPN transistor in saturation, the base may be more positive than the collector. However, because the emitter is more heavily doped than the base, the base gets a very heavy electron concentration. Some of these electrons recombine with holes in the base. Some of these electrons find their way to the base electrode and leave the transistor. But in a typical transistor, most of these electrons *diffuse* over the base-collector junction, even though the base is more positive. This is a concrete example of diffusion having a greater effect than drift. And that is why charges seem to flow in a counter-intuitive way in a saturated BJT.

Edit: Just to be clear, although the majority of electrons in the base of a *saturated* BJT *diffuse* over the base-collector junction, when the BJT is NOT saturated, but in the forward active region, that is, when the collector of an NPN transistor is more positive than the base, in that case, *drift* of electrons over the base-collector junction plays a major role.

> I've come across this which contains important hints. It claims Vce can be lower than Vbe, but its claim of Vce being 0.2 isn't backed with references to datasheets

Although the lowest Vce attainable in saturation may not be found it a datasheet, a Vce of 0.2 is commonly attainable by many (if not most!) BJTs.

Answer (score 0):

BJT saturation in an ideal transistor would result in a VCE of 0 V.

Many transistors will show a VCEsat of 100-200 mV when the collector current is low enough, and VCE usually less than 0.5 V at their rated max collector current. TTL output stages include a BJT to ground, and they specify a maximum output voltage of 400 mV when sinking (IIRC) 16 mA to ground.

Some transistors are designed for very low VCEsat at rated currents, Zetek specialised in this.

When a data sheet shows a transistor having a much higher VCEsat (1.5 V is unusually high), this is a maximum figure to be used when designing for heat, voltage drop etc in what is likely to be a power transistor, and is dominated by the residual collector emitter resistance, not by any basic transistor mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

*BJT: How can the potential of B be above that of C during saturation?*

Here comes a short answer:

Why should it not be possible?

When due to a sufficient value of Vbe the collector current has a value which causes such a high voltage drop across the collector resostor Rc that Vce<Vbe (which means Vcb<0), the B-C junction is biased in forward direction.

As a consequence, the current Ib into the base node now consists of two parts (through the B-E junction as well as the B-C junction).
Therefore, the classical relation Ib=Ic/B does not apply anymore.
As a consequence, a base current Ib much larger than anticipated by the B-value is a good indication for saturation.

In this context, it is interesting to realize that - for practical purposes - we do assume that we need such a large base current Ib (some people even say: we inject such a large current Ib) to bring the BJT into saturation.